# How to highlight TeX code?

Tags: listings, highlighting, syntax-highlighting

I want to highlight some **TeX code** listings, so I use `lstlisting`.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX] 
\begin{tabular}{ |p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Country List} \\
\hline
Country Name & ISO ALPHA 2 & ISO ALPHA 3 \\
\hline
Afghanistan & AF & AFG \\
Aland Islands & AX & ALA \\
Albania & AL & ALB \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{lstlisting}
```

My `lstset` is:

```
\lstset{extendedchars=\true,keepspaces=true,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=flexible,
escapechar=$,escapebegin=\[,escapeend=\]
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                        
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
```

But I'm not happy with the result - only `end` became magenta and other text is black:

[image: Result]

I believe `begin` is a keyword on an equal basis with `end`, but it's black too.
Is there any way to make TeX code highlighted?

Comment: See also [listings package - Can I include a backslash \ in language keyword (\begin) for syntax highlighting in LaTeX code? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17774/listings-package-can-i-include-a-backslash-in-language-keyword-begin-for) for some customization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem arises from asking `listings` to highlight TeX code when you are actually giving it LaTeX code. In TeX `\begin`, `\hline`, `\multicolumn`, etc. are not used and are accordingly not highlighted. Simply change your language to LaTeX by adding `language=[LaTeX]{TeX}` to your `\lstset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}
\lstset{extendedchars=\true,keepspaces=true,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=flexible,
escapechar=$,escapebegin=\[,escapeend=\]
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                        
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    language=[LaTeX]{TeX} %<--
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Country List} \\
\hline
Country Name & ISO ALPHA 2 & ISO ALPHA 3 \\
\hline
Afghanistan & AF & AFG \\
Aland Islands & AX & ALA \\
Albania & AL & ALB \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]